# Should a client pay to fix broken features because of changes in third party APIs?

Tags: api, clients

**Is it reasonable to ask a web development client to pay to fix features that are now broken because of third party APIs?**

Examples:

- We integrate a Twitter feed into a site's homepage, which works fine for months, and then one day just dies because Twitter change their API
- A spell-checking feature that relies on Google's spelling API one day goes down because Google decide to close down that API

Can we realistically ask a client to pay for our time to fix those things?  Or should we absorb the cost of that in order to maintain an ongoing relationship with them?

In some cases, we set up and monitor the hosting for our clients, so there is some level of expectation that we keep their site up and running.  Other clients arrange their own hosting.  Does that affect the answer to the question?

And how do other industries handle this kind of problem?

Comment: Really down to how your business runs and there's no right or wrong answer and very opinionated. Please use the chat channel for asking questions as such, were active in there and check it many times. I've left a message on their for you which my 'personally opinion'.

Comment: OK, thanks bybe.  Unfortunately the chat isn't that useful because I've never seen it show up in Google results (and I've never looked at it until just now).  Can I reword the question somehow to make it fit the SE format?